# How to do object recognition with OpenCV?

Tags: android, image-processing, opencv

I try to make an application which should use the camera in the background (hidden preview) to detect a blinking LED light and count the blinking in a specified time frame (frequency).

However, I searched the net up and down and after a whole day of compiling and troubleshooting the OpenCV integration in my eclipse projects I finally am able to compile running samples of OpenCV without any errors (my PC seems to be a f***ing mess). Now, the samples lack code documentation and I'm still stuck at the very beginning...

Is anybody here at stackoverflow who did work with OpenCV on Android successfully and could give me a hand? Every breadcrumb is a highly welcomed information ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd be glad and could perhaps help you if you were a bit more specific. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: as I see it from my point I do have a great lack of understanding which filters/transformations are necessary to reach my goal, which is nothing that OpenCV could be blamed for... but I also do not have an insight at the library itself and where I can find a proper tutorial or description how one could process a `VideoCapture` stream... my english is also limited as I'm no native speaker so I'm limited to find words for my problem here - I'm sorry ;)

Comment: No problem, you're not the only one not being fluent in english here ^^. What I want is more information about your problem. To make it simpler, is it how to find the steps to achieve your objective, or how to run the code, or how to put the code on your device. . . We want as much as possible to help you. I can help you with image processing and opencv functions, but not is this is an android-related problem.